# json php (Problems trying to exctract values)

Tags: php, json

Hope someone can help me :)

I have a json to decode and i want to get some values in it but, i fail trying ...

The json to decode is this one :

> `$string = '{"TEAM-d2dbb890-813d-11e3-9ae1-782bcb4ce61a":{"fullId":"TEAM-d2dbb890-813d-11e3-9ae1-782bcb4ce61a","name":"La line Up","tag":"LILU","status":"RANKED","teamStatSummary":{"fullId":"TEAM-d2dbb890-813d-11e3-9ae1-782bcb4ce61a","teamStatDetails":[{"fullId":"TEAM-d2dbb890-813d-11e3-9ae1-782bcb4ce61a","teamStatType":"RANKED_TEAM_5x5","wins":4,"losses":2,"averageGamesPlayed":0},{"fullId":"TEAM-d2dbb890-813d-11e3-9ae1-782bcb4ce61a","teamStatType":"RANKED_TEAM_3x3","wins":0,"losses":0,"averageGamesPlayed":0}]},"roster":{"ownerId":21428398,"memberList":[{"playerId":23907761,"joinDate":1390159075000,"inviteDate":1390158849000,"status":"MEMBER"},{"playerId":21075924,"joinDate":1390158942000,"inviteDate":1390158852000,"status":"MEMBER"},{"playerId":21428398,"joinDate":1390158907000,"inviteDate":1390158856000,"status":"MEMBER"},{"playerId":29513977,"joinDate":1390158926000,"inviteDate":1390158911000,"status":"MEMBER"}]},"matchHistory":[{"kills":30,"deaths":51,"opposingTeamKills":51,"assists":50,"gameMode":"CLASSIC","opposingTeamName":"stavaclaroxd","win":false,"invalid":false,"mapId":1,"gameId":1284144814,"date":1390258314682},{"kills":9,"deaths":24,"opposingTeamKills":24,"assists":12,"gameMode":"CLASSIC","opposingTeamName":"Infinity gaming v2","win":false,"invalid":false,"mapId":1,"gameId":1282462494,"date":1390169929005},{"kills":32,"deaths":9,"opposingTeamKills":9,"assists":53,"gameMode":"CLASSIC","opposingTeamName":"Suburban Syndicate Squad","win":true,"invalid":false,"mapId":1,"gameId":1282421677,"date":1390167736333},{"kills":22,"deaths":3,"opposingTeamKills":3,"assists":32,"gameMode":"CLASSIC","opposingTeamName":"SKTlT5","win":true,"invalid":false,"mapId":1,"gameId":1282362755,"date":1390165366740},{"kills":24,"deaths":9,"opposingTeamKills":9,"assists":35,"gameMode":"CLASSIC","opposingTeamName":"нELLO HELLо","win":true,"invalid":false,"mapId":1,"gameId":1282304277,"date":1390163366886},{"kills":35,"deaths":11,"opposingTeamKills":11,"assists":58,"gameMode":"CLASSIC","opposingTeamName":"нELLO HELLо","win":true,"invalid":true,"mapId":1,"gameId":1282260799,"date":1390161678373}],"createDate":1390158828000,"modifyDate":1392723897000,"lastJoinDate":1390159075000,"secondLastJoinDate":1390158942000,"thirdLastJoinDate":1390158926000,"lastGameDate":1390422192000,"lastJoinedRankedTeamQueueDate":1390421982000}}';`

I did something but with no result :

```
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);
$json_a[TEAM-d2dbb890-813d-11e3-9ae1-782bcb4ce61a][name]
```

That was a fail ... if someone can help me, I would be happy :)

Best regards,
CUETO Vincent

Comment: Try $json_a['TEAM-d2dbb890-813d-11e3-9ae1-782bcb4ce61a']['name']

Comment: try json_encode[{"kills":35,"deaths":11,"opposingTeamKills":11,"assists":58,"gameMode":"CLASSIC","opposingTeamName":"нELLO HELLо","win":true,"invalid":true,"mapId":1,"gameId":1282260799,"date":1390161678373}],"createDate":1390158828000,"modifyDate":1392723897000,"lastJoinDate":1390159075000,"secondLastJoinDate":1390158942000,"thirdLastJoinDate":1390158926000,"lastGameDate":1390422192000,"lastJoinedRankedTeamQueueDate":1390421982000}}';

Comment: `var_dump($json_a)` will you exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

echo the value

```
echo $json_a['TEAM-d2dbb890-813d-11e3-9ae1-782bcb4ce61a']['name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an array, but stdclass - {} not [].
Try:

```
$json_a->{'TEAM-d2dbb890-813d-11e3-9ae1-782bcb4ce61a'}->name
```

Comment: This answer is correct.